# libssl.so.0.9.8 on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, openssl

I am trying to install the Common LISP web server Hunchentoot on an ec2 instance (using the Amazon Linux AMI). One of the Hunchentoot dependencies asks for "libssl.so.0.9.8". Hunchentoot apparently can't use the current version of OpenSSL (1.0.0). Also, I can't find "libssl.so.0.9.8" in the standard ec2 package repo. What is the best way to get this older lib and all of it's dependencies?

Edit: The local Linux guru told me to compile 0.9.8 myself into /opt, that's what I'm doing currently. We'll see how that works.

Comment: Do you have openssl-devel and openssl098e installed?

Comment: @cyberx86 : openssl 1.0.0 is installed. Are those 2 packages available in the Amazon Linux repo?

Comment: @cyberx86 : Thank you! Installing those packages worked! Do you want to post that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search of the amzn repository on my server shows the following:

```
yum provides */openssl-devel
...
/usr/lib/libssl.so
...
```

and

```
repoquery --list openssl098e*
...
/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8e
...
```

Both (openssl-devel and openssl098e) are from the amzn repository - traditionally, the devel package is used when compiling other packages against openSSL, but perhaps the other one will work for you.